# How to get local ip address of UDP packet sender in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have coded a ip to ip video chat application using JMF for my brothers school project. In which first of all one of the user sends an udp as a chat request to another system. Then the second system sends a reply to the first system after that video chat starts. Every thing is working perfectly while there is no router b/W two systems(e.g. Both are on same lan or connected to internet via usb modem). else when i retrieve the sender's ip from UDP packet it gives the ip of router through which the sender is connected to internet so when second system replies to the request of chatting the first system never receives the reply. So how can i get the local ip of the UDP sender.

Thanks every one in advance.

Comment: At the very least, you need a server with a public IP do NAT traversal, so you might as well route all the traffic through that server if you have only a small client base

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about NAT traversal and it's a really hard problem. There's more on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal.

If it's just for a school project, I would just make it work on a local network and not bother with NAT traversal.